# GRU included CNN for text Generator

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

I try to integrate CNN to GRU. My model gets the image through CNN. The features from CNN will pass to the GRU frame by frame. The structure is shown in the picture.

[image]
This is my example code that implemented follows the above structure.
encoder :

```
### input Image size [batch,seq,colorch,hight,weight]
### expext output 

class CNNencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size,batch_size =5):
    super(CNNencoder, self).__init__()
    self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.modelVGG = models.vgg11(pretrained = False)
    self.modelVGG = self.modelVGG.to(self.device)

    self.adaptor = nn.Linear(8192, self.hidden_size)
    self.adaptor = self.adaptor.to(self.device)
    
    self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True, bidirectional=False)  ## (inputSize, hidden_size)
    self.gru = self.gru.to(self.device)
    self.batch_size = batch_size

def forward(self, input, hidden):
    seqs = input.size()[1]
    for indexseq in range(0, seqs):
        inputImageBatch = input[:, indexseq,:,:,:].view(-1,3,128,128)
        features = self.modelVGG.features(inputImageBatch)
        
        flat_features = features.view(features.size(0), 1,-1)  # flatten
        if indexseq == 0:
            output = flat_features
        else:
            output = torch.cat((output, flat_features), dim=1)

    # output = flat_features    ## expected   [batch,seq,features]
    outputAdaptor = self.adaptor(output)
    outputGru, hidden = self.gru(outputAdaptor, hidden)
    return outputGru, hidden

def initHidden(self):
    return torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size, device=self.device)
```

I would like to know. How CNN parameter will get gradient through time?
If I create a model from this class and execute loss.backword().
loss values get from decoder section.